# Редактирование значения переменной byte[] и string в собраном C# .net приложении

Tags: c#, .net, dnlib

Есть собраное приложение c# .net в котором есть класс в котором находятся переменные byte[] и string. требуется изменить значения этих переменых из другого приложения c#.
byte[] будет разного размера как и string.
byte[] обьявлен таким способом:

```
public static byte[] Soft = new byte[] {0x55,0x44,.....}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?

Comment: Берёте dnlib и делаете, в чем именно вопрос?

Comment: @aepot У меня нету опыта с работой dnlib. Я пробовал через field.constant(не работает из-за того что базовый массив не может быть константой), field.InitialValue(не работает так как размер массива изменяется и надо править класс/тип).

Comment: оно? https://stackoverflow.com/q/29543935/12888024

Comment: @aepot
Нет. Строка и байтовый масив это разное. Как мне известно строка сразу записывается в поле, а байтовый масив сначала создаёт поле а потом в .cctop инициализирует его значениями, или я что-то не так понимаю?